# PHP - very basic XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlreader

Because I will be parsing a very large XML file, I am trying to use XMLReader to retrieve the XML data, and use simpleXML to display. I have never used XMLreader, so I am simply trying to get a basic feel for using XMLReader.  I want to display all the name and price values in the XML file, and I cannot get this code to display anything. Am I missing something?

Here is the XMLReader/simpleXML code:

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('products.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument;

while ($z->read() && $z->name === 'product') {
$node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

var_dump($node->name);
$z->next('product');
}
```

Here is the XML file, named **products.xml**:

```
<products>

<product category="Desktop">
<name> Desktop 1 (d)</name>
<price>499.99</price>
</product>

<product category="Tablet">
<name>Tablet 1 (t)</name>
<price>1099.99</price>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop condition is broken. You loop if you get an element AND that elements name is "`product`". The document element is "`products`", so the loop condition is never `TRUE`.

You have to be aware that `read()` and `next()` are moving the internal cursor. If it is on a `<product>` node, `read()` will move it to the first child of that node.

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open($file);
$dom   = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// look for the first product element
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'product') {
  continue;
}

// while you have an product element
while ($reader->localName === 'product') {
  $node = $reader->expand($dom);
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(@category)', $node),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $node),
    $xpath->evaluate('number(price)', $node)
  );
  // move to the next product sibling
  $reader->next('product');
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Desktop"
string(14) " Desktop 1 (d)"
float(499.99)
string(6) "Tablet"
string(12) "Tablet 1 (t)"
float(1099.99)
```

Comment: Thanks! You steered me in the right direction - enough to where I can hopefully incorporate simpleXML into displaying the results after XMLReader parses the XML.

Comment: I prefer using DOM+XPath. SimpleXML is to much work.

Comment: In working with this, I believe you are correct about simpleXML being too much work. I'm relatively new to programming, so I appreciate your help!