# Parse & query XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am using the below code in PHP to parse a XML file and retrieve a certain information from the file.

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('File.xml');
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Hotel') {
        $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true);
        $dom->appendChild($node);
        $h1name = $xpath->evaluate('string(/Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$hotelCodes[0].'"]/HotelName)', $node);
        $dom->removeChild($node);
        if ($h1name) {
         $reader->close();
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a VPS with CENTOS x64 , SSD drive, 1GB of ram and a 1.8 ghz CPU.
The code works but is very slow.
If i parse a 20 mb file it takes ~1 minute fo the page to load.

Could you please help to improve the code so i can get a faster working solution ?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate question here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167062/best-way-to-process-large-xml-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - very basic XMLReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072961/php-very-basic-xmlreader)

Comment: Actually your current source is not bad, if you check my answer in the linked you will see an optimization. Use `$reader->next('Hotel');` to go directly to the next Hotel node.

Comment: @ThW where should  $reader->next('Hotel'); be fit  after $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true); ?