# How to parse an XML node with a colon tag using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlreader

I am trying to fetch the value of the following nodes from [this URL (takes quite some time to load)][1]. The elements I'm interested in are:

```
title, g:price and g:gtin
```

The XML starts like this:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>PhotoSpecialist.de</title>
    <link>http://www.photospecialist.de</link>
    <description/>
    <item>
      <g:id>BEN107C</g:id>
      <title>Benbo Trekker Mk3 + Kugelkopf + Tasche</title>
      <description>
        Benbo Trekker Mk3 + Kugelkopf + Tasche Das Benbo Trekker Mk3 ist eine leichte Variante des beliebten Benbo 1. Sein geringes Gewicht macht das Trekker Mk3 zum idealen Stativ, wenn Sie viel draußen fotografieren und viel unterwegs sind. Sollten Sie in eine Situation kommen, in der maximale Stabilität zählt, verfügt das Benbo Trekker Mk3 über einen Haken an der Mittelsäule. An diesem können Sie das Stativ mit zusätzlichem Gewicht bei Bedarf beschweren. Dank der zwei besonderen Kamera-Befestigungsschrauben können Sie mit dem Benbo Trekker Mk3 sehr nah am Boden fotografieren. So nah, dass in vielen Fällen die einzige Einschränkung die Größe Ihrer Kamera darstellt. In diesem Set erhalten Sie das Benbo Trekker Mk3 zusammen mit einem Kugelkopf, Socket und einer Tasche für den sicheren und komfortablen Transport.
      </description>
      <link>
        http://www.photospecialist.de/benbo-trekker-mk3-kugelkopf-tasche?dfw_tracker=2469-16
      </link>
      <g:image_link>http://static.fotokonijnenberg.nl/media/catalog/product/b/e/benbo_trekker_mk3_tripod_kit_with_b__s_head__bag_ben107c1.jpg</g:image_link>
      <g:price>199.00 EUR</g:price>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      <g:identifier_exists>TRUE</g:identifier_exists>
      <g:brand>Benbo</g:brand>
      <g:gtin>5022361100576</g:gtin>
      <g:item_group_id>0</g:item_group_id>
      <g:product_type>Tripod</g:product_type>
      <g:mpn/>
      <g:google_product_category>Kameras & Optik</g:google_product_category>
    </item>
  ...
  </channel>
</rss>
```

To get this, I have written the following code:

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('https://my.datafeedwatch.com/static/files/1248/8222ebd3847fbfdc119abc9ba9d562b2cdb95818.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument;

while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item')
    ;

while ($z->name === 'item')
{
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());
    $a = $node->title;
    $b = $node->price;
    $c = $node->gtin;
    echo $a . $b . $c . "<br />";
    $z->next('item');
}
```

This returns me only the title...price and gtin are not showing.

Comment: My bad, you're using [**SimpleXMLElement** to access the attributes with their own namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6576773/367456). So the linked duplicate is not entirely correct (you could just use [`XMLReader::expand()`](https://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.expand.php) to obtain the **DOMElement** directly, convert to DOM via `dom_import_simplexml` or for sure access the namespaced attributes via SimpleXML directly like in  the linked Q&A in this comment).

Comment: @hakre...i can't use simplexml as the XML is large so XMLReader is to be used

Comment: Huh? You actually use SimpleXML in your questions code. I was not speaking about switching away from **XMLReader** when I mentioned it.

Comment: @hakre...oops sorry...actually am very new to this XML coding...btw can you please help me with this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The elements you're asking about are not part of the default namespace but in a different one. You can see that because they have a prefix in their name separated by the colon:

```
  ...
  <channel>
    <title>PhotoSpecialist.de</title>
    <!-- title is in the default namespace, no colon in the name -->
    ...
    <g:price>199.00 EUR</g:price>
    ...
    <g:gtin>5022361100576</g:gtin>
    <!-- price and gtin are in a different namespace, colon in the name and prefixed by "g" -->
  ...
```

The namespace is given with a prefix, here "g" in your case. And the prefix the namespace stands for is defined in the document element here:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
```

So the namespace is "`http://base.google.com/ns/1.0`".

When you access the child-elements by their name with the **SimpleXMLElement** as you currently do:

```
$a = $node->title;
$b = $node->price;
$c = $node->gtin;
```

you're looking only in the default namespace. So only the first element actually contains text, the other two are created *on-thy-fly* and are yet empty.

To access the namespaced child-elements you need to tell the **SimpleXMLElement** explicitly with the `children()` method. It creates a new **SimpleXMLElement** with all the children in that namespace instead of the default one:

```
$google = $node->children("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");

$a = $node->title;
$b = $google->price;
$c = $google->gtin;
```

So much for the isolated example (yes, that's it already).

A full example then could look like (including node-expansion on the reader, the code you had was a bit rusty):

```
<?php
/**
 * How to parse an XML node with a colon tag using PHP
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/29876898/367456
 */
const HTTP_BASE_GOOGLE_COM_NS_1_0 = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0";

$url = 'https://my.datafeedwatch.com/static/files/1248/8222ebd3847fbfdc119abc9ba9d562b2cdb95818.xml';

$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// move to first item element
while (($valid = $reader->read()) && $reader->name !== 'item') ;

while ($valid) {
    $default    = simplexml_import_dom($reader->expand($doc));
    $googleBase = $default->children(HTTP_BASE_GOOGLE_COM_NS_1_0);
    printf(
        "%s - %s - %s<br />\n"
        , htmlspecialchars($default->title)
        , htmlspecialchars($googleBase->price)
        , htmlspecialchars($googleBase->gtin)
    );

    // move to next item element
    $valid = $reader->next('item');
};
```

I hope this both gives an explanation and broadens the view a little on **XMLReader** use as well.

Comment: @hakre..thanks for such nice informative post...its a tutorial for me thanks once again

Comment: An even  better variant might be with using DOMXpath. But I have remembered this too late now :) ThW had such an example with **XMLReader**, I take a look if I find a link. --- ***Edit:*** here it is, the example fits really nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23079179/367456

Comment: "only the first element actually contains text, the other two are created on-thy-fly and are yet empty" - that's not really true; *all* the child elements or attributes are *retrieved* on-demand ([here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#246), ultimately), it's just that the call to `->elements($ns)` or `->attributes($ns)` tells SimpleXML *which* ones to retrieve. I find SimpleXML feels less surprising if you think of it as an *API*, like the DOM but simpler, rather than as objects which "contain" data.

Comment: @IMSoP; I like your description (I've read some of your recent answers in the SimpleXML tag, really *very* well written, makes me a bit jealous but hopefully my English profits from reading) but some of those elements are also created when accessed, at least when you write data into them: https://eval.in/319535 - that's what I meant with create on the fly. The original document didn't contain that element (this is for `$b` and `$c` in my answer above).

Comment: @hakre Ah, I think I see what you mean, but they won't be created just by reading them: https://eval.in/319537 Since the question is only about reading, the fact that you *could* create them by assigning a value is kind of by-the-by. Still, an interesting point that referencing them isn't *invalid*, just *not useful for the current task*. :)

Comment: @IMSoP: Actually following the lxr link you gave shows those are created if they yet not exist. SimpleXMLElement returns an object here (hence the API), so I must say that in the end, created on the fly by the API isn't that wrong, isn't it? ^^ :) http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#358

Comment: @hakre My reading was that a new *object* is created every time the property access handler is used, regardless of node (element/attribute) existence - so even elements returned fine are "created on the fly". I'm not entirely clear how that works for non-existent nodes (both because my C skills are rudimentary, and because of the shocking scarcity of comments in the source), but it clearly doesn't imply any changes to the underlying document structure, since the XML output is not changed.

Comment: @IMSoP: I don't know 100% from C code but in userspace: Non-existent nodes are empty elements. It's not possible to create empty elements on empty elements. That is, the parent element must exist, the child is added on the fly. On an on-the-fly added child you can't add another child (let's try that: https://eval.in/319618  yes, like that).

Comment: And if you want, create a question :) we can garden it for reference. Let's keep it in Q&A form here on SO, no need to bury this into comments :)

Answer (score 0):

If the main tag is a **string with colon**, you must use

```
$xml->next($xml->localName);
```

to move to the next item element.