# PHP SimpleXml can not access a node value using : character

Tags: php, xml

I do load an XML string using :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data['MyXml']['xml']);
```

And could get the value from all the nodes using this sintax:

```
$xml->MyNode->AnotherNode->MyFinalNode[0];
```

But there is a node that uses : as a separator and i could not get the value :

```
$xml->MyNode->AnotherNode->abc:MyFinalNode[0];
```

How can i access the value from this node using PHP simplexml functions ?

For example, how can i access the D node into :

```
<my:A>  
    <my:B>
        <my:C>  
            <my:D>
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_string` has a parameter `string $ns = ""`, and read about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an XML node with a colon tag using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876898/how-to-parse-an-xml-node-with-a-colon-tag-using-php)