# LoadXML file too big

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to load xml content from a URL containing about 60MB of data. When I do that using simple XML built in library I keep getting the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): internal error: Huge input lookup in Entity, line: 845125
```

And the script is being stopped. What's wrong? How can I deal with this?

Sample url I use:

```
http://foo.com/feed.xml
```

Comment: Either increase you PHP memory limit, or depending on what you want to do with the XML, try a forward only reader rather than a full XML object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php

Comment: Target xml has error and browser didn't load it.

Comment: Use XMLReader to iterate the feed entries, expand them to DOM and use Xpath to fetch the detail for each entry. This way only a single entry node and its descendants will be loaded into memory. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23079179/2265374